How to use FontAwesome in Vue 3 without using modules?
I'm migrating a project from Vue 2 to Vue 3. This project uses the global Vue object. There's no imports or modules. Every tutorial looks the same, from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#font-awesome:
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'; // Ensure your project is capable of handling css files
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import { aliases, fa } from 'vuetify/iconsets/fa';

export default createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'fa',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      fa,
    },
  },
});

They usually go on to also mention registering the FontAwesome component:
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
...
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

The hurdle I can't get over is I can't find a way to access fa, aliases, and the component on the Vuetify object and Vuetify doesn't seem to have a Vuetify-fa.js that I can tell.
How can I add font-awesome to Vue 3 without using modules?

I've found Vuetify.components.VClassIcon which lets me specify the component used to render icons. This specific component will add the icon string as a class instead of setting the icon property which is what was happening by default. Now, my icons still weren't showing up but I found all that was missing was the fa class that Vue 2 would add to the icon but for some reason Vue 3 wasn't. So I added a default.
const vuetify = Vuetify.createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    'VIcon': {
      class: 'fa',
    },
  },
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'fa',
    sets: {
      fa: {
        component: Vuetify.components.VClassIcon,
      }
    }
  },
  ...
};

This seems to check all the boxes I need checked right now. I won't mark this as the answer yet. I want to hear from other people who might know a better way.
